# Derivative of $y^T(Ax)$

Tags: derivatives

I'm not familiar with derivations of equations involving vectors and matrices. Given

$$f(x)=c^Tx + y^TAx$$

with $y \in \mathbb{R}^d, A \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the derivative of $f(x)$? Somehow $c^T + y^TA$ can not be right since the second term yields a matrix and no scalar as in $f(x)$.

Comment: What do you *really* mean $\frac{df}{dx}f(x)$?

Comment: Making the derivative of f with regards to the vector x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is linear in $x$ 
$$
f(x)=(\underbrace{c+A^Ty}_{=d})^Tx=d^Tx=d_1x_1+d_2x_2+\ldots+d_nx_n.
$$
The derivative of $f(x)$ for $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is the gradient which is defined as a vector of partial derivatives
$$
\nabla f(x)=\left[\matrix{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f\\ \vdots\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}f}\right]=
\left[\matrix{d_1\\d_2\\\vdots\\d_n}\right]=d=c+A^Ty.
$$
P.S. You did right, but it is common to think of the gradient as a *column* vector.

Comment: Isn't it actually usual that Jacobian matrix is $(\partial_jf_i)_{ij}$?

Comment: Yes, in this sense the gradient becomes the *transposed* Jacobian. One can say that it is more natural to define gradient=Jacobian, i.e. a row vector, but it is convenient to think of $x$ and $\nabla f$ to be the elements of the same $\mathbb{R}^n$ as columns. It is just an agreement. At least I have seen it to be defined as a column more often than otherwise.